# How do I stop pg_search from returning all columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I have a pg_search_scope in a class called Name as follows:

```
pg_search_scope :fuzzy_search, 
                :against => [:surname, :forename, :other_names],
                :using => {
                   dmetaphone: {
                      tsvector_column: 'dmetaphone_search_vector'
                   },
                tsearch: {
                   dictionary: 'english',
                   tsvector_column: 'dictionary_search_vector'
                   }
                },
                :ranked_by => ":trigram"
```

I need to run a SELECT against the scope and just get back selective columns. I excepted the following todo that:

```
Name.select(:surname).fuzzy_search('smith')
```

but that generates:

```
SELECT surname, \"names\".*, ((similarity((coalesce(\"names\".\"surname\"::text, '') || ' ' || coalesce(\"names\".\"forename\"::text, '') || ' ' || coalesce(\"names\".\"other_names\"::text, '')), 'smith'))) AS pg_search_rank FROM \"names\"  WHERE (((\"names\".\"dmetaphone_search_vector\") @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || pg_search_dmetaphone('smith') || ' '''))) OR ((\"names\".\"dictionary_search_vector\") @@ (to_tsquery('english', ''' ' || 'smith' || ' ''')))) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, \"names\".\"id\" ASC
```

So as we can see that leaves `\"names\".*` in the query, which ofcourse returns all the columns.

Anyone else come across this? Any suggestions?

:)

Answer (score 0):

Can the `select` statement come after the `fuzzy_search` call:

```
Name.fuzzy_search('smith').select(:surname)
```

If that doesn't work, try [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
Name.fuzzy_search('smith').pluck(:surname)
```

Comment: Hi bschaeffer, thanks for the suggestion but no joy I'm afraid. The pluck is kinda too effective, it removes the generated pg_search_rank column as well as the regular \"names\".* columns. This then causes the order by statement to blow up because it orders on the pg_search_rank field. The first suggestion of putting the select after the fuzzy_search still leaves the \"names\".* in the sql. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this same issue over and over before finally figuring out a fix:

```
Name.fuzzy_search('smith').map(&:surname)
```

It's not ideal, because (as I understand it) it's technically loading all the fields before stripping away everything except `:surname`. But better than nothing, I suppose.

Comment: By the way, the pg_search functionality has been updated, so now `select` can be chained to produce the desired effect. See the relevant PR here: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/pull/202.